# Sentence in which Past Perfect is not thought of as preceding the action

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect

I can’t just wrap my head around it...

In which sentence the action denoted by the Past Perfect is not thought of as preceding the action denoted by the Past Indefinite tense:

a) He knew where hilda lived, but he had never been there;

b) They waited quietly till he had finished;

c) She had come before he phoned over

Initially, I thought that the right answer was b, because I applied the same logic to the sentence as it would be in Present Tenses, that is, that part after till denoting some sort of a future action, and in this case, Past Perfect was more for me as a successive thing. Thus, it seemed to me that the correct answer was b. But, my logic wasn’t quite right, was it?

Comment: Who's asking the question? If it's a grammar text, you should be aware that the question itself is phrased ungrammatically.

Comment: It was on my exam. Though it was not specifically an English exam, rather tangent to it as you could see. 

So, could you explain the meaning of the second sentence to me? Is my line of reasoning false (last paragraph)?

Comment: Hared to judge if the text is not copied right. Where is the word *over*? She had come **over** before he phoned over?

Comment: In some sense, the action denoted by the past perfect precedes the action denoted by the simple past in all three clauses.  In (a), the action in the second clause never happens, but it doesn't happen in the time period before the time that the first clause references. In (b), they stop waiting after he finishes. In (c), she comes before he phones over. This is not a good question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a "rule" that the past perfect should always be the first/earliest/earlier action. It is guidance only. Do not try to make the language fit "rules".

The guidance applies to main clauses.

In

b) They waited quietly till he had finished;

c) She had come before he phoned over

*till he had finished* and *before he phoned over* are adverbial clause modifying "waited". Subordinate clauses need not follow the guidance - and they often do not. The subordinate clauses are there to add to the main clause.

In *a) He knew where hilda lived, but he had never been there;*, *but he had never been there* is a main clause and follows the guidance. His never having been there must precede his knowing where she lived.

Comment: But in (a), both "he knew where Hilda lived" and "he had never been there" are statements that apply to an extended period of time, so saying one happened before the other is a very vague statement.

Comment: With all the infirmities of the question, a) might be the expected answer because there is no option like "none of the above".